# Powershell pipeline foreach-object variable is null

Tags: powershell

I have a super simple script that I swear I use almost every day, but for some unknown reason my $_. variable is null.

Could someone please spot check it? there is only one column in the CSV I am importing, however it has no header so i don't know if that is what is causing it.

```
$results = import-csv C:\####\####\####\finddestinguishednamesof.csv | foreach-object { 
Get-ADGroup $_. -Properties SamAccountName,DistinguishedName
}
$results | select SamAccountName,DistinguishedName |
Export-Csv C:\Users\laruemi\Desktop\test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I keep getting this error and do not know why.

```
Get-ADGroup : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The Identity property on the argument is null or empty.
At C:\Users\laruemi\Desktop\getdestinguishedname.ps1:2 char:13
+ Get-ADGroup $_. -Properties SamAccountName,DistinguishedName
+             ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ADGroup], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroup
```

The list of CSV's I am importing is just a list of SAMAccountNames with no header. i dont think that should cause this error, but it might. Can someone please give me a sanity check?

Comment: why do you have a dot after `$_` ?

Comment: `Get-ADGroup $_.` **-->** `Get-ADGroup $_`

Comment: that still gives me the same error:   Get-ADGroup : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The Identity property on the argument is null or empty.
At C:\Users\laruemi\Desktop\getdestinguishedname.ps1:2 char:13
+ Get-ADGroup $_ -Properties SamAccountName,DistinguishedName
+             ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ADGroup], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroup

Comment: If your CSV file is a valid CSV file with headers you should provide the correct column header to specify what value you want  to use. `$_.Identity` or `$_.sAMAccountName` for example

Comment: Thank you all. that helped me fix it